# Access to the datastore of my application on AppScale

Tags: cassandra, datastore, appscale

I'm trying to access to the datastore of my GoogleAppEngine application that i deployed on AppScale. But i have this error "google.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc.AppScaleAuthenticationError: Unable to authenticate with AppScale."

```
root@appscale-image0:~/appscale/AppServer/google/appengine/tools# python remote_api_shell.py -s 192.168.33.10:8080
Email: test@test.tt
Password: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "remote_api_shell.py", line 161, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "remote_api_shell.py", line 157, in main
    appengine_rpc.HttpRpcServer)
  File "remote_api_shell.py", line 85, in remote_api_shell
    rpc_server_factory=rpc_server_factory)
  File "/root/appscale/AppServer/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 703, in ConfigureRemoteApi
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
  File "/root/appscale/AppServer/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 546, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
    response = server.Send(path, payload=None, **urlargs)
  File "/root/appscale/AppServer/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py", line 557, in Send
    "with AppScale.")
google.appengine.tools.appengine_rpc.AppScaleAuthenticationError: Unable to authenticate with AppScale.
```

Anyone have an idea that can help me.

Thnks.

Comment: Please edit your question and add any relevant sections of your code, so we can figure out what's going wrong with it.

Comment: It's not my code. I'm just using this [step](https://github.com/AppScale/appscale/wiki/Viewing-Data-in-AppScale-%28remote_api%29#connect-to-the-remote-shell) to connect to the datastore.

Comment: Which version of AppScale are you using? Did you enable remote_api in your builtins?

Comment: I recommend also creating a test account with a password that only has alphanumeric characters. See if some character is messing up the authentication portion. Let us know the character in question if that is the case and we'll get a fix for it.

Comment: - AppScale version : 2.1.0.
- remote_api : enabled.
- account's password with only letters.
It seem's that the problem isn't her

Comment: I created a new account, and it's work fine. But still didn't work with admin account. thanks

Comment: Have an other problem right now.I have a file named "models.py" in my app, i wanna import it to uses my db classes, but it tell me "ImportError: No module named models". Any idea ?